# Latin-1 non ASCII symbol on Mono Linux is not displayed

Tags: c#, linux, encoding, fonts, mono

Our winforms software extensively using ° - degree symbol. Which is &deg or &#176 in ISO/IEC 8859-1 (also known as Latin-1).

There is no problem with the symbol on .NET Windows for decent number of fonts (We use about 5 fonts in app). There is no problem with ° on Linux in general. I can see it in Gtk applications, even can input °, say, in console if typing ctrl+shift+u-b-0, but not in our Mono application.

When we run the software under Mono on Linux (Ubuntu 12.10) the degree symbols are not displayed (black question chars are rendered instead).

Is there any way to configure mono or our software (select fonts?) to have the symbols shown?

P.S. The software is for equipment for precision angle measurement. Degree symbol for the software is like dollar symbol for a bank.

**Update** (For commenters). We can theoretically replace each ° with picture. It is possible, the same as Man on Mars is possible. But before we start this tedious work, my idea was to ask on stackoverflow, because maybe we can just tweak something in Mono (as usual with mono). What is wrong with that?

Comment: "The symbol is deeply integrated in business logic" - shouldn't that be in presentation logic?

Comment: We live not in an ideal world. The software is written for almost 10 years, since .net 1.1. One of the core struct - Angle has &deg in ToString method. It was for debug reasons. But now it is everywhere. From the other point of view - it is a SYMBOL. How to change it? Put pictures everywhere?

Comment: Why aren't you using Unicode/wide characters/whatever C#/Winforms uses for L10N?

Comment: How to write ° with it? Once again, it is a symbol. Standard symbol. Windows, winforms, Linux, stackoverflow has no problems with it.The software is for precision angular equipment. Degree symbol for the software is like dollar symbol for the bank)

Comment: Except `$` is in ASCII and `°` is not.

Comment: That is great. How it does helps with question?  Windows, winforms, Linux, stackoverflow renders °. Consider the question is ° + Mono = ?

Comment: The answer is one of: 1) Use Unicode/wide characters, not CP1252/narrow characters; 2) There is a bug in Mono's implementation of Winforms. While your problem *is* important, it most likely is [not caused by the latter](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html).

Comment: The symbol displays correctly in a `PropertyGrid` on Ubuntu 12.10 with Mono 2.10.8.1 using the default DejaVu Sans font.

Comment: @mike: Did you create the application on a Windows system?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No, built on that box.

Comment: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=569011

Comment: Thank you! Confirm that DejaVu Sans works for property grid, labels, text. 

Now the only thing left is DataGridView. Can't make it show ° still

Comment: @mike z, could you make your comment as answer, so I could set it as right answer? When I set DejaVu Sans to dataGridViewCell directly, it showed ° correctly. This means that probably cell style is overwritten at some point, but generally DejaVu Sans works for it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled an application on Ubuntu 12.10 with Mono 2.10.8.1 and the degree symbol appears fine in `PropertyGrid` and `Label` controls. The default font appears to be DejaVu Sans, so you might want to consider using that.